# Material UI IconButton tooltip is not shown correctly

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

In my reactJS applickation I use Material UI and react-bootstrap-table.

In a cell I use the Material UI `IconButton` like this:

```
 <IconButton tooltip={t('tooltips:editRegulation')} tooltipPosition={'left'}
     onClick={() => this.props.history.push("/pms-records/edit/" + row.pmsFindingId)}>{cell}}>
     <FontIcon className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"/>
 </IconButton>
```

Result is this:

[image]

The tooltip is cut by the table cell borders. I tried to change the `z-index` and read this: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/5912

But no solution.

Any hints for me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible stackblitz link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cell has for sure a css that states `overflow: hidden`.
You can render the tooltip in a [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) but you'll eventually lose the position of your element. **Better to override the table-cell CSS**

In GitHub linked issue:

> I got it fixed by adding style={ { overflow: 'visible' } } to the
>   TableRowColumn that IconButton resides in.

Comment: The issue is still related on a CSS that controls the overflow of the table-cell, maybe your scaffolding is not the same or you are not overriding the css correctly. If you have a public page reachable I can point you out to the right direction

Comment: @ Mosè Raguzzini   I have the same issue where i display a tooltip in a container with overflow:scroll and the ToolTip clips to the side of the container, how can i override the overflow property, is there any other way?